# Разные поля в форме yii2

Tags: yii2, форма, валидация

Привет=)
Кто может подсказать, нужно сделать форму которая изменяет поля ввода в зависимости от выбранного.

Небольшой пример:
Есть несколько разных систем пополнения, у каждой системы есть определенный набор полей, как сделать так чтоб при нажатие на одну из системы в форме отображались поля для ввода конкретно для этой системы и валидация тоже должна быть.
Количество полей для каждой системы отличается, условия валидации тоже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы попробовал сделать табами, а на сервере валидация по сценарию.

Comment: @fedornabilkin, а можно сценарий передать динамически из формы?

Comment: А почему нет? Добавить скрытый инпут, при смене таба, писать в инпут сценарий. Хотя это не совсем изящно получается.

Comment: Можно добавить PJax на форму - при клике на одну из систем пополнения - запрос отправляется на сервер, и в контроллере в зависимости от выбранной системы выводим нужную форму

Comment: @fedornabilkin, а как правильнее будет сделать?

Comment: Я бы написал для каждой системы пополнения свой экшн в контроллере, а в табах для каждой свою форму. В контроллере определяешь что валидировать по конкретному сценарию, а в экшенах (вроде) указываешь текущий сценарий.

Comment: @fedornabilkin понял, спасибо! буду пробовать если что напишу=)

Comment: @fedornabilkin Я тут подумал, а как допустим если я хочу сделать динамические системы? (добавление/удаление)

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то для каждой системы делаешь вид (подвид), в контроллере создаешь массив в с названиями и статусами (вкл/выкл), а в главном виде, в котором табы с системами, выводишь подвиды для каждой системы согласно данным из массива в контроллере. Если надо много и часто изменять систему, то лучше их определять не в массиве, а в БД. Плохо только, что для каждой системы надо будет делать свой файл подвида, в котором прописывать форму с полями.

Comment: @fedornabilkin вот в том то и дело, что нужно как-то сделать редактирование всего через админку, заказчик же не будет код править=)  Я думал сделать что-то типо динамических правил которые можно включать и выключать в соответствии с требованиями системы, а в виде сразу будут прописаны все поля которые будут показываться в зависимости от правил модели.  Только как это сделать еще не придумал=)

Comment: Делай две таблицы. В одной название системы, айдишник, статус и т.д., во второй набор правил. Для каждой системы свой набор правил будет храниться во второй таблице. В виде прописываешь все необходимые поля и отображаешь в зависимости от набора правил для конкретной системы. Лучше конечно сделать генератор полей, чем все в виде прописать.

Comment: @fedornabilkin что за генератор полей?

Comment: Паттерн декоратор знаешь? Вероятно он подойдет в данном случае.